# Invoke Javascript inside WebView UWP

Tags: webview, uwp

I want to add below content to my webview

```
    <html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
 <div id="mydiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" ></div> 
    <script src="https://mydomain/Embed.js" type="text/Javascript">
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code looks like this

```
 <WebView x:Name="wView"></WebView>
```

Code behind

```
wView.NavigateToString(
            @"<html> <body> <h1>My First Heading</h1> <div id=""mydiv"" style=""width: 100%; height: 100%;"" ></div> <script src=""https://mydomain/Embed.js"" type=""text/Javascript""> </script> </body> </html>");
```

With this approach, I am unable to run any javascript inside `Embed.js`. Only content inside H1 tag is getting displayed. how can I make sure the javascript inside webview (Embed.js in my case) gets executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of `WebView.NavigateToString()`:

> NavigateToString supports content with references to external files such as CSS, scripts, images, and fonts. However, it does not provide a way to generate or provide these resources programmatically.

Therefore, a better way to make js effective is to create an HTML file in the project, write your HTML content into it, and use it in the following method:

```cs
wView.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Html/myHtmlFile.html");
```

### Update

If you need to dynamically modify the content of the HTML file, then `ms-appx-web` is not appropriate, because it is directed to the files in the package, and the files in the package cannot be modified directly at runtime.

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview?view=winrt-19041#navigating-to-content). You can save the html text in `LocalFolder`'s subfolder as a temporary file and guide it through **ms-appdata**:

```cs
var htmlFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("html", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
var localFile = await htmlFolder.CreateFileAsync("temp.html", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(localFile, html);
wView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/html/temp.html"));
```

*P.S. Temporary files must be stored in a subfolder of LocalFolder, and there can be no links to the same level*

Comment: in my scenario, inside the HTML I have to embed some dynamic content, so I won't be able to save it as HTML. if I did ao each time before loading the webview i have to change the content of HTML file programmatically, which won't be the right way to do this. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Hello, I modified my answer, please kindly check it.